# How to replace numeric value with string representation in JSON?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file with several uid fields that are numeric but I need to convert them to string.  These uid fields are nested in different places in the file.

```
e.g.   "uid": 891602734537070110  => "uid": "891602734537070110"
```

I tried this command:

```
jq '(.. | .uid?) |= (tostring)'
```

which somewhat worked but it added a "uid" field (e.g.  "uid": "null") to any dictionaries that didn't have one to begin with.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Just beware that those are very large numbers. It will have double precision so the values may actually end up different as a string. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1741

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing this is `walk`:

```
walk(
  if type == "object" and has("uid")
  then .uid |= tostring
  else . end
)
```